# Rxswift Map and Zip not Called

Tags: swift, swiftui, rx-swift

I am trying to get the element of 2 observables produced asynchronously and pass them as parameters to a function once both are received.

However my map operator in my ViewModel below is not executed and the breakpoint just skips over it.

```
ViewModel.swift

init(api: ApiService) {
        self.api = api
    }

func getData1() -> Observable<Data1> {
        return api.getData1()
    }

    func getData2()  -> Observable<NewViewModel> {
        return Observable.create { observer in

            let disposable = Disposables.create()
            self.api.getData2()
            .map {
                $0.arrayOfStuff.forEach { (stuff) in
                    let background = stuff.background

                let newViewModel = NewViewModel( background: self.spotlightBackground)
                observor.onNext(newViewModel)
                }
            return disposable
            }
        }
```

In my ViewController i am creating the **Zip** of the observables because newViewModel[getData2] may return later and i want to call the function when both observables emit a value

in my viewDidLoad() i setup zip by subscribing and adding observables

```
let zippy = Observable.zip(viewModel.getData1(), viewModel.getData2()).subscribe(onNext: { (data1, newViewModel) in
            self.layoutSetUp(data1: data1, newViewModel: newViewModel)
            })
        zippy.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

```
private func layoutSetUp(data1: Data1, newViewModel: NewViewModel) {


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view = SwiftUIHostingView(rootView: SwiftUIContentView(data1: data1, newViewModel: newViewModel))
        }
    }
```

This is not executing and no values are passed to function either and im not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData2` method never emits a value so neither will the zip. The code in the method is a bit too muddled for me to understand what you are trying to do so I can't tell you exactly what you need, but I *can* say that when you have an observable that nothing is subscribed to, then it will not emit a value.

This bit:

```
self.api.getData2()
    .map {
        $0.arrayOfStuff.forEach { (stuff) in
            let background = stuff.background

            let newViewModel = NewViewModel(background: self.spotlightBackground)
            observor.onNext(newViewModel)
        }
        return disposable
    }
```

Is an observable with no subscribers.